# cmake/make uses g++4.2 under mac os x 10.6 snow leopard

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, cmake

hey I have to build a framework (https://github.com/vrsys/programmiersprachen-raytracer) for my computer science class using cmake and make. I'm using os x 10.6.8 and installed g++4.8 and cmake with macports, but I have no idea how to set g++4.8 as default compiler for cmake and make. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

GNU make implicit rules use the variable `$(CXX)`, and explicit rules usually follow this pattern.  The [default value is `g++`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html), but this can be overridden in the makefile or on the `make` command-line.

Evidently, the default `g++` on your system is 4.2.  In addition to the two methods of overriding mentioned above, you could export `CXX=g++-4.8` to your environment in a start-up script to save the per-case hassle.  Cmake evidently uses the same variable, so doing this should work for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, blow away any CMakeCache.txt you may have (cmake doesn't like changing compilers), and then do something like this:

```
set CC=<location of gcc-4.8>
set CXX=<location of g++4.8>
```

Then run cmake again.. It should choose those compilers instead, and then MAke will use whatever CMake tells it too.

Comment: I added them to the CMakeLists.txt but it didn't work. when I run cmake .. he still uses 4.2. if I run make after that this is the error :  79%] Building CXX object framework/CMakeFiles/framework.dir/pixel.cpp.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
make[2]: *** [framework/CMakeFiles/framework.dir/pixel.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [framework/CMakeFiles/framework.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2